# Using android's grid layout with different DPI on the same screen size and resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, i got two tablets, both got 7" screen and 1024 x 600 resolution, one is using 160dpi and the other 240dpi (probably changed on build.prop). I'm trying use a grid layout but my problem is, the layout showing bigger than my screen on the 240dpi tablet (1,5 times bigger).
What can i do in order to make the both layouts works in the same way? or at least the 240dpi renders entirely inside my screen?![enter image description here][1]

I'm making two lines of buttons on the center of the screen using this code

```
gl = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);
    for(int i = 0;i<11;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<15;j++)
        {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setWidth(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/15);
            b.setHeight(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/11);
            if(j== 7 || i==5)
            {
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
            else
            {
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            gl.addView(b);
        }
    }
```

But it is showing like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVL0.jpg

My layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="15"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="11" >
```

The software were made to work in the white  one (see picture) by people who worked in my company before me but now I have to make it work on both.

Comment: By definition, two devices with the same screen size and resolution will have the same DPI. They may declare that they will use different density buckets for resources, but the density itself is in pixels (resolution) per inch (size) and therefore will be the same. Beyond that, you will need to post your layout XML, and ideally also upload some screenshots somewhere and link to them, so we can see what effects you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative values for the screen layout, not pixels or dp.

The root cause is that one of your tablets is reporting an incorrect pixel density. The native density of both displays is close to 160 dpi. The 240dpi tablet will appear to Android as if it had a 5" display, and Android will scale the fonts to be the same size.

If that causes screen real estate issues on the 240dpi tablet, do the following:

- Create a copy of your layout in one of the following folders:

  - `layout-w1024dp` if width is an issue
  - `layout-h600dp` if height is the main limiting factor
- In the main layout, decrease the font size to work on the 240dpi tablet.

This will reduce the font size to get more content on the screen if the screen size is below a certain minimum. However, fonts may appear tiny on a really small screen (devices with less than 7" which report correct pixel density).

As for relative values: I have done this extensively with linear layouts but not with grid layouts so far, but maybe this helps you get started.

Suppose you have a horizontal LinearLayout (child items arranged in columns) and you want them to maintain the same width relative to each other, taking up the whole screen.

For each child layout, set its `layout_width` to `0dp` and give it a `layout_weight`.

The `layout_weight` is fairly arbitrary – it is just the ratio that matters, as the ratio of the layout_weight parameters of the child layouts equals the ratio of their widths. Hence having three child layouts with a `layout_weight` of 2 vs. 1 vs. 2 will have the same effect as 200 vs. 100 vs. 200.

For the LinearLayout holding all of these, specify a `weightSum` that is the sum of its children's `layout_weight`. Set the parent's `layout_width` to `fill_parent`.

Comment: I posted a little more details about my problems, can you give a second look please?